# everything is too small and resolution is too big on ionic mobile device

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic5

I have an ionic project. I have completed this project and compiled it for both ios and android. Although there does not appear to be a problem for Android, there is a problem for iOS. I also have a problem when selecting a device from Chrome's mobile view. On Chrome mobile view and iOS devices, everything looks too small, too small to be read. But in android it is normal size without any problem.

[Example ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHBdQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

When developing in Ionic you need to check when you're setting some style configs for your classes, specially if they're something like .md classes, because in Ionic it uses .md for android devices and .ios for ios devices. So it seems your configurations are just being applied in those classes, and you'll need to do the equivalent for your ios classes.

Comment: what kind of configuration? Sorry, I did not fully understand. Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

I just forgot the meta tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```